Unable to index %T in Power Automate
I am trying to find the index of %T\tCURRTYPE in the variable called cont which store the below text

ERMHDR\t19.12\t2024-03-22\tProject\tmatt.rou\tMatt Roultte\tdbxDatabaseNoName\tProject Management\tU.K.\r\n%T\tCURRTYPE\r\n%F\tcurr_id\tdecimal_digit_cnt\tcurr_symbol\tdecimal_symbol\tdigit_group_symbol

I am using the below formula but it always returns -1
indexOf(variables('cont'), '%T\tCURRTYPE')

What is wrong with the formula
I tried replacing \t with an actual tab by copy pasting from notepad but it still doesnt work, but if i just search for CURRTYPE it gets me the correct position. looks there is something with the extended characters which is causing the problem
